# any way to move existing app to another space on iMac?

Tags: macos, mac

I have several applications opened. I would like to move some to another space. I an not sure if this is possible? I could set up applications in space settings but I don't want to do this for finder. I just want to move two opened finders to another space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or just drag the window (click and hold the top) at the same time you switch spaces (on my computer it's `Command+arrow key`) and the window will follow your cursor into the space you just switched to. I find this easier than waiting (when moving to an edge) or using exposé.

Comment: I also just realized its Control+arrow by default.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this

1. click and move it to an edge (left,right,top,bottom) and hold it there for a couple of seconds and it will 'pop' into the next space.
2. If you are using exposé you can see all spaces at once and drag an app from one to the other.